# How to change page numbering style in each subfile?

Tags: formatting

Let's assume my thesis consists of 3 parts: Acknowledgment, Abstract, and Body. Acknowledgment and Body are subfiles. I want each section to have different page numbering styles:

Acknowledgment: Page 1 of x, Page 2 of x, etc.

Abstract: (start over) i, ii, iii, etc.

Body: (start over) The regular 1, 2, 3

How do I do this? Here is a simplified project file:

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\title{Thesis title}
\author{Me}
\date{May 2023}

\begin{document}

\subfile{different style.tex}

\newpage

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    I want this part to be in another style, for example, i, ii, iii.
\end{abstract}

\newpage

\section{Regular style 1, 2, 3}
\subfile{regular style.tex}
   
\end{document}
```

`different style.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
I want this to be in this style: Page 1 of x, page 2 of x, etc.\\
I want to thank...
   
\end{document}
```

`regular style.tex`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
This can be a regular style. 1, 2, 3
\end{document}
```